# Найти уникальные строки

Tags: c#, unique-ptr

Всем привет, хочу найти уникальные строки при чтении файла

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ТЕСТОВЫЙ МЕТОД ПОИСКА ПО МАСКЕ(ХОЧУ, ЧТОБЫ ИСКАЛО ТОЛЬКО СРЕДИ ВЫДЕЛЕННЫХ ФАЙЛОВ)

        {
            searchMask(listBox1);
        }

        void searchMask(ListBox listBox1) // Метод поиска по маске

        {
            string rootFolder = @"C:\Users\lavraschuk\Desktop\Files";
            string pattern = @"\b(ArtId=[^a-z][^|][^,][^*][0-9]*)\b|\b(TeNam=[^a-z][^|][0-9]*)\b|\b(ResPickLstId=)\b[0-9]*|\b(PlNamOld = FZG[0-9]*)\b|\b(LvsBsmBoBst::getBstMgOnTe:Rtc dMg=)[0-9]*\b|\b(LvsTpmBoTpa::aenEzl:Aendern Endziel)\b|\b(SlsDaoFzg_T::dbUpdate:UPDATE Fzg_T.FzgNam=[0-9]*)\b";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\lavraschuk\Desktop\Target\target.txt"))

                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))

                {

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, System.Text.Encoding.Default))

                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

                        {

                            string newstring = line.Substring(0, 8);
                            Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                            //string SubString = file.Substring(file.Length - 36);
                            var name = Path.GetFileName(file);

                            if (match.Success)

                            {
                                var jk = (name + " " + newstring + " " + match.Value);
                                sw.WriteLine(jk);
                            }

                            else
                                sw.Write("");
                        }
                    }
                }

            MessageBox.Show("File txt is ready");
        }
```

txt файл, к которому обращаюсь:

```
22:39:36,382         0 ms        15 ms DEB |  |  |  |  |  LvsBsmSqlBstByTeNE::fetch:   1. RESULT : Bst_T|BstId=126121986|ArtId=000100000012277000011050|TeNamTrg=2217186|TeNam=1126812|BstMg=3|BstKnzAnbr=1|BstKnzGal=1|SprGrundNam=010|BstQlf=10(NORM)|BstChgNam=DBNULL|BstChgNam5=DBNULL|BstDzMhd=DBNULL|BstMrk=DBNULL|GpNamLief=Ажуруна|BstSerienNr=DBNULL|BstGew=DBNULL|AupRef=DBNULL|LgoNam=WMS|WeaId=00010000ПН015900|WepNr=25|AufId=DBNULL|AupNr=DBNULL|LttNamVpEh=PAKET1|BstWwsBelegPos=DBNULL|BstDzWwsBeleg=DBNULL|BstDzFifo=01.11.2018 00:00:00|BstKnzStl=DBNULL|BstIdUbo=DBNULL|BstIdTrg=DBNULL|BstGrpPack=DBNULL|FzgNam=DBNULL|BstMgPk=DBNULL|DzIns=12.11.2018 12:42:42|DzUpd=10.01.2019 16:17:26|NamUpd=TskMdt3/228|Tsn=59|
22:39:36,382         0 ms        15 ms DEB |  |  |  |  |  LvsBsmSqlBstByTeNE::fetch:   1. RESULT : Bst_T|BstId=126121986|ArtId=000100000012277000011050|TeNamTrg=2217186|TeNam=1126812|BstMg=3|BstKnzAnbr=1|BstKnzGal=1|SprGrundNam=010|BstQlf=10(NORM)|BstChgNam=DBNULL|BstChgNam5=DBNULL|BstDzMhd=DBNULL|BstMrk=DBNULL|GpNamLief=Ажуруна|BstSerienNr=DBNULL|BstGew=DBNULL|AupRef=DBNULL|LgoNam=WMS|WeaId=00010000ПН015900|WepNr=25|AufId=DBNULL|AupNr=DBNULL|LttNamVpEh=PAKET1|BstWwsBelegPos=DBNULL|BstDzWwsBeleg=DBNULL|BstDzFifo=01.11.2018 00:00:00|BstKnzStl=DBNULL|BstIdUbo=DBNULL|BstIdTrg=DBNULL|BstGrpPack=DBNULL|FzgNam=DBNULL|BstMgPk=DBNULL|DzIns=12.11.2018 12:42:42|DzUpd=10.01.2019 16:17:26|NamUpd=TskMdt3/228|Tsn=59|
22:39:36,382         0 ms        15 ms DEB |  |  |  |  |  LvsBsmSqlBstByTeNE::fetch:   1. RESULT : Bst_T|BstId=126121986|ArtId=000100000012277000011054|TeNamTrg=2217186|TeNam=1126812|BstMg=3|BstKnzAnbr=1|BstKnzGal=1|SprGrundNam=010|BstQlf=10(NORM)|BstChgNam=DBNULL|BstChgNam5=DBNULL|BstDzMhd=DBNULL|BstMrk=DBNULL|GpNamLief=Ажуруна|BstSerienNr=DBNULL|BstGew=DBNULL|AupRef=DBNULL|LgoNam=WMS|WeaId=00010000ПН015900|WepNr=25|AufId=DBNULL|AupNr=DBNULL|LttNamVpEh=PAKET1|BstWwsBelegPos=DBNULL|BstDzWwsBeleg=DBNULL|BstDzFifo=01.11.2018 00:00:00|BstKnzStl=DBNULL|BstIdUbo=DBNULL|BstIdTrg=DBNULL|BstGrpPack=DBNULL|FzgNam=DBNULL|BstMgPk=DBNULL|DzIns=12.11.2018 12:42:42|DzUpd=10.01.2019 16:17:26|NamUpd=TskMdt3/228|Tsn=59|
22:39:37,382         0 ms        15 ms DEB |  |  |  |  |  LvsBsmSqlBstByTeNE::fetch:   1. RESULT : Bst_T|BstId=126121986|ArtId=000100000012277000011051|TeNamTrg=2217186|TeNam=1126812|BstMg=3|BstKnzAnbr=1|BstKnzGal=1|SprGrundNam=010|BstQlf=10(NORM)|BstChgNam=DBNULL|BstChgNam5=DBNULL|BstDzMhd=DBNULL|BstMrk=DBNULL|GpNamLief=Ажуруна|BstSerienNr=DBNULL|BstGew=DBNULL|AupRef=DBNULL|LgoNam=WMS|WeaId=00010000ПН015900|WepNr=25|AufId=DBNULL|AupNr=DBNULL|LttNamVpEh=PAKET1|BstWwsBelegPos=DBNULL|BstDzWwsBeleg=DBNULL|BstDzFifo=01.11.2018 00:00:00|BstKnzStl=DBNULL|BstIdUbo=DBNULL|BstIdTrg=DBNULL|BstGrpPack=DBNULL|FzgNam=DBNULL|BstMgPk=DBNULL|DzIns=12.11.2018 12:42:42|DzUpd=10.01.2019 16:17:26|NamUpd=TskMdt3/228|Tsn=59|
22:39:37,382         0 ms        15 ms DEB |  |  |  |  |  LvsBsmSqlBstByTeNE::fetch:   1. RESULT : Bst_T|BstId=126121986|ArtId=000100000012277000011051|TeNamTrg=2217186|TeNam=1126812|BstMg=3|BstKnzAnbr=1|BstKnzGal=1|SprGrundNam=010|BstQlf=10(NORM)|BstChgNam=DBNULL|BstChgNam5=DBNULL|BstDzMhd=DBNULL|BstMrk=DBNULL|GpNamLief=Ажуруна|BstSerienNr=DBNULL|BstGew=DBNULL|AupRef=DBNULL|LgoNam=WMS|WeaId=00010000ПН015900|WepNr=25|AufId=DBNULL|AupNr=DBNULL|LttNamVpEh=PAKET1|BstWwsBelegPos=DBNULL|BstDzWwsBeleg=DBNULL|BstDzFifo=01.11.2018 00:00:00|BstKnzStl=DBNULL|BstIdUbo=DBNULL|BstIdTrg=DBNULL|BstGrpPack=DBNULL|FzgNam=DBNULL|BstMgPk=DBNULL|DzIns=12.11.2018 12:42:42|DzUpd=10.01.2019 16:17:26|NamUpd=TskMdt3/228|Tsn=59|
```

Comment: `var uniqueLines = File.ReadAllLines("filepath").GroupBy(x=>x).Where(x=>x.Count() == 1).Select(x=>x.Key).ToArray();`

Comment: Нет, не чтобы читались уникальные, а чтобы в результат выводились уникальные

Comment: `foreach(var line in uniqueLines) PrintResult(line);`? - вот вывод. Ну, или ваш вопрос мне попросту непонятен.

Comment: tym32167 вам дал код, который соберет уникальные строки файла в список, вам осталось лишь сделать ваше преобразование (`name + " " + newstring + " " + match.Value`), сконкатенировать элементы списка в string с сепаратором "новая строка" и записать результат в файл

Comment: @АнтонГридюшко просто попробуй код Тима. Он реально дал достаточное количество кода.